# Why does this concurrent HTTP client randomly crash?

Tags: concurrency, go, channel

I'm learning Go by writing an HTTP testing client like Apache's `ab`. The code below seems pretty straightforward: I create a configurable number of goroutines, each of which sends a portion of the overall HTTP requests and records the result. I iterate over the `resultChan` channel and inspect/record each result. This works find when the number of messages is, say, 100. When I increase the number of messages, however, it hangs and htop shows VIRT of 138G for the process.

Here's the code in question:

```
package main

import "net/http"
import "fmt"
import "time"

const (
    SUCCESS   = iota
    TOTAL = iota
    TIMEOUT = iota
    ERROR = iota
)

type Result struct {
    successful    int
    total         int
    timeouts      int
    errors        int
    duration      time.Duration
}

func makeRequests(url string, messages int, resultChan chan<- *http.Response) {
    for i := 0; i < messages; i++ {
        resp, _ := http.Get(url)
        if resp != nil {
            resultChan <- resp
        }
    }
}

func deployRequests(url string, threads int, messages int) *Result {
    results := new (Result)
    resultChan := make(chan *http.Response)
    start := time.Now()
    defer func() {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", time.Since(start))
    }()
    for i := 0; i < threads; i++ {
        go makeRequests(url, (messages/threads) + 1, resultChan)
    }

    for response := range resultChan {
        if response.StatusCode != 200 {
            results.errors += 1
        } else {
            results.successful += 1
        }
        results.total += 1
        if results.total == messages {
            return results
        }
    }
    return results
}

func main () {
    results := deployRequests("http://www.google.com", 10, 1000)
    fmt.Printf("Total: %d\n", results.total)
    fmt.Printf("Successful: %d\n", results.successful)
    fmt.Printf("Error: %d\n", results.errors)
    fmt.Printf("Timeouts: %d\n", results.timeouts)
    fmt.Printf("%s", results.duration)
}
```

There are obviously some things missing or stupidly done (no timeout checking, channel is synchronous, etc) but I wanted to get the basic case working before fixing those. What is it about the program as written that causes so much memory allocation?

As far as I can tell, there are just 10 goroutines. If one is created per HTTP request, which would make sense, how does one perform operations that would create many goroutines in a loop? Or is the issue totally unrelated.

Comment: VIRT is just the virtual memory, it doesn't bear much meaning in assessing real memory usage, look at RES.

Comment: haven't evaluated the code yet, but please, *never* ever do benchmarks against some else's servers! You may just be getting throttled by google here.

Comment: @JimB It doesn't actually hit google, it hits a local server. I just changed that for clarity's sake.

Comment: @nos if a process is consuming 138GB of virtual memory, it at least means it tried to allocate that much, regardless of how much is currently resident. Clearly all of the memory can't be resident as most is being held in swap space.

Comment: @jknupp, I'm willing to bet you're running OSX. Go can show huge vmem allocations on that platform (can't remember why offhand), but vmem doesn't mean much, it's just address space for the program.

Comment: @jknupp No it does not say that, and it very likely does not reside in swap space. Virtual memory is just an entry in the kernel that says here's the start and end address of memory you can touch. Nothing needs to be allocated anywhere if the application never touches it. it's quite common for garbage collected runtimes to just reserve a huge chunk of virtual memory, since doing so is 100% free when it's unused, as doing so eases the language runtime implementation. See also [this](http://golang.org/doc/faq#Why_does_my_Go_process_use_so_much_virtual_memory)

Comment: @nos The issue, however, is that that allocation wasn't occurring during a working run (and does not now occur that the issue is fixed). The virtual memory size is quite low. To say that "virtual memory is just an entry in the kernel" is a) wrong and b) misleading, as something *does* need to allocate the memory for it to be reserved, regardless of if it's being used or not. The golang runtime doesn't seem to just reserve 100+ GB RAM.

Comment: @jknupp No, virtual memory *does not* need to be allocated in any way to be reserved, just a simple entry for a range of memory addresses is made. The actual memory is faulted in as it's referenced. What is not keept track of, per process, is how much of the virtual memory is used though. Only the memory that's used and physically allocated is kept track of (that's the RES or rsize column.) I've quite a lot of go programs that does reserve many many GB of virtual memory, this is not a problem, unless the virtual memory is actually used.

Comment: @nos I think there's something getting lost in translation here. What I'm saying is that the kernel does not just randomly decide to reserve 138GB for a process; rather, the process has to do *something* to ask the kernel to reserve that space. Not *every* go program reserves at least 138GB of memory *every time*, much less every *program*.

Comment: @jknupp Ofcourse not. I'm just saying it does not in any way indicate an error, or that something is necessarily wrong, or that much memory is actually used.

Comment: You can safely remove ` = iota` from all your constants in that `const` block except the first -- that's what the code in the standard library does anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the sequence leading to the hang is:

1. `http.Get` in `makeRequests` fails (connection denied, request timeout, etc.), returning a `nil` response and an error value
2. The error is ignored and `makeRequests` moves on to the next request
3. If any errors occur, `makeRequests` posts less than the expected number of results to `resultChan`
4. The `for .. range .. chan` loop in `deployRequests` never breaks because `results.total` is always less than `messages`

One workaround would be:

If `http.Get` returns an error value, post a `nil` response to `resultChan`:

```
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        resultChan <- nil
    } else if resp != nil {
        resultChan <- resp
    }
```

In `deployRequests`, if the `for` loop reads a nil value from `resultChan`, count that as an error:

```
for response := range resultChan {
    if response == nil {
        results.errors += 1
    } else if response.StatusCode != 200 {

    // ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the issue. I forgot I had removed the error checking line when refactoring the program. I solved this issue a slightly different way:
        if err != nil {
          fmt.Println(err)
          resultChan <- new (http.Response)
        }

Comment: Why would you send an uninitialized http response pointer?  You can't use it.  Just send nil.  You may also want to consider closing your response bodies.  Your tool should probably read the response bodies as well.  io.Copy + ioutil.Discard will help.  Oh, and never ignore errors